# MSSQL update and set a column with certain value

Tags: sql-server, set, conditional-statements

I have a problem on updating a column in MSSQL,
so basically i have a database like this

```
no     U1     U2     U3     U4
1      12     -1     10     -1
2      12     15     -1     11
3      -1     17     10     11
4      12     -1     10     11
```

My goal is to update columns that have -1 value look on no. 1, it have two -1 value on U2 and U4,
what I want is to update the first -1 value (which is U2 from no 1 on that example), with a value I want/I declare, and I just want to update from no 1, not updating no 4 U2 too...

How to accomplish this?

Comment: This is a bit unclear. Are you saying you want a query with a single parameter that will scan row by row, find the first -1 entry, replace it with that parameter, and exit the procedure?

Answer (score 2):

Use where clause of UPDATE statement eg:

```
update table1
set U1 = case U1 when -1 then 123 else U1 end,
    U2 = case when U1 != -1 and U2 = -1 then 123 else U2 end,
    U3 = case when -1 not in (U1, U2) and U3 = -1 then 123 else U3 end,
    U4 = case when -1 not in (U1, U2, U3) and U4 = -1 then 123 else U4 end
where [no] = (select top 1 [no] from table1 where -1 in (U1, U2, U3, U4))
```

Comment: There are few improvements of the query, you may find solution also in some of the previous more simple version

Comment: The query is not syntactically correct. It points to the right direction though.

Comment: this seem to work, but i have until U300, do i need to set U1-U300? o.O, and, can i set for example : set U1 = case U1 when -1 then @value else U1 end, thanks before :)